# Error when making a "FORK" cluster and registerDoSNOW in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a parallel process I've had working in R for a while using a FORK cluster over a PSOCK (due to the speed and memory overhead of PSOCK) and registering the backend using registerDoParallel. I wanted to include a progress bar to see how far along my code is (sometimes if can run for hours or days depending on the number of iterations) and to see if any changes help speed up my code. Sadly, I can't include a progress bar with doParallel, but I can with doSNOW. Problem is, if I use doSNOW with a FORK I get this error "no application method for 'sendData' applied to an object of class "c('forknode', 'SOCK0node')". It works flawlessly with a PSOCK though, but I have the memory issues with PSOCK I'd like to avoid. How do I get around this? Am I unable to use a FORK with doSNOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(author of the [Futureverse](https://www.futureverse.org/) here)

You can use `foreach()` with [**doFuture**](https://dofuture.futureverse.org/) and then the `multicore` **future** backend for forked parallelization. This will allow you to use [**progressr**](https://progressr.futureverse.org) for progress updates.

Here's an example adopted from https://progressr.futureverse.org/#foreach-with-dofuture:

```r
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()  ## %dopar% parallelizes via future
plan(multicore)     ## forked parallel processing (via 'parallel')

library(progressr)
handlers(global = TRUE)
handlers("cli")     ## how progress is reported

my_fcn <- function(xs) {
  p <- progressor(along = xs)
  foreach(x = xs) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(6.0-x)
    p(sprintf("x=%g", x))
    sqrt(x)
  }
}

my_fcn(1:5)
■■■■■■■■■■■■                     40% | x=4 ETA:  3s
```

PS. This will also allow you to move away from depending on the **snow** package, which is considered deprecated and is now falling behind of improvements that have been done to the **parallel** package.

Comment: Thank you! How does this compare to FORK and PSOCK as far as processing speed and memory overhead goes?

Comment: You question is rather broad, but `plan(multicore)` uses the `parallel::mclapply()` framework. If you like to use a FORK cluster, do `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n, type = "FORK")` and then `plan(cluster, workers = cl)`.  If you like to use a PSOCK cluster, do `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n, type = "PSOCK")` and then `plan(cluster, workers = cl)`.

Comment: Ah thank you. I was reading the vignette and got a bit confused, as it said in there that plan(multicore) uses a Fork. Im trying to go with the framework that has the smallest memory overhead and is also very fast. My understanding is that a FORK can give me that. Am I correct in my assumption, or is multicore better?